# Resource estimate for ab initio calculation

Tags: molecular-structure, energy, intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics, ab-initio

I have recently come across this very intriguing paper “[The Fundamental Vibration of Molecular Hydrogen](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6390.pdf)”.

I have asked the authors the following naïve questions directly via email?

1. What was the amount of computer memory used by the full ab initio calculation?
2. What was the time-to-solution of the full ab initio calculation?

While I wait for their response, could anyone help me to make a ball park estimate of those two answers?

Comment: The folks over at Matter Modeling might have estimates.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been cross posted and answered on matter modeling